# Using a Variable as a Parameter - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass a variable through to be used as a parameter within a function. I'm not even sure if this is possible but below is what i am attempting to accomplish, what i have tried so far keeps kicking out a "positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument" error

```
$Var = Read-host "enter Attribute number"
$CustomAtt = "CustomAttribute$Var"

Get-Mailbox -Identity $Email | Set-Mailbox -$CustomAtt "TestTest"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set cmdlet arguments that way in powershell. You can do what your are attempting to do by using a feature called [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2). Simply store your arguments in an array or hashtable and then apply them to the cmdlet using `@` symbol.

Like this:

```
$mailBoxAttributes = @{
    $CustomAtt = "TestTest" }

Get-Mailbox -Identity $Email | Set-Mailbox @mailBoxAttributes
```

Comment: This did solve the issue, with some tweaking at least,. I realized i was doubling up cmdlets and dropped the Get-mailbox completely and just splatted in the identity and customattribute.